# How does the leading coefficient determine the rise and fall of an odd degree polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

How does the leading coefficient determine the rise and fall of an odd degree polynomial?
What is the proof of this statement?

A) 
If the leading coefficient is positive ( greater than zero ), then the graph falls to the left and rises to the right.

B) 
If the leading coefficient is negative ( less than zero ), then the graph rises to the left and falls to the right.

Comment: Well, I would just consider $\lim_{x \to - \infty}$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty}$ of the polynomial ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me show the argument for cubic polynomial:
$f(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ Write it this way: 
$$f(x) = x^3 \bigg(a + \frac bx +\frac c{x^2} +\frac d {x^3}\bigg)$$

For high positive values of $x$ the expression inside the bracket is:  $a+ $ something going to zero.  The expression outside the bracket which is $x^3$ goes to infinity, so depending on the sign of $a$ you get what you want. Clear to see the degree 3 is chosen only for convenience, this argument works for other degrees too.